Cannot create Azure B2C Tenant
My app contains a way to authenticate using email address and password, currently done using Firebase. I want to transition my app from Firebase authentication to an Azure service. I think I found that this service is Azure AD B2C.
I tried following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant , but I can't seem to do it: there is no option to create an Azure B2C tenant. There is no such option, neither at the Azure AD B2C page and not at B2C Tenants. What am I doing wrong?
I have a very simple organisation: one tenant, one subscription, and a few resource groups. There are a few users, but I am logged in with the user with the Owner role, so it should not be a permissions issue right?

Here is a link that should work: https://portal.azure.com/?feature.msaljs=true#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/CreateDirectoryBlade/preselectB2C~/true/tenantType/b2c.
You can also find it by going to Marketplace and searching for "azure ad b2c". It was the second result for me.
